# Os.path.sep issue on Windows when rendering template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Os.path.sep returns \\

Having issue with this path when trying to render a template:

```
#1: This doesn't work:

path = os.path.join('file', 'name.html')
render_template(path )
#path is: 'file\\name.html'
# In broswer, it shows this error: 
# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: file\name.html

#2: This works:
path = os.path.join('file', 'name.html').replace('\\', '/')
render_template(path )
#path is: 'file/name.html'
```

If I open the windows file explorer and copy 'file\name.html' from the location of the script where this line is called, it works fine, so why #1 cannot find the template but #2 can?

Answer (score 1):

According to the section [Loaders](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#loaders) in Jinja's documentation loading templates from the filesystem is performed by `jinja2.FileSystemLoader` class. There is a call to the function `split_template_path()` that parses incoming path and checks its sanity inside this class (see *site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py*), and sanity checking is performed by extracting tokens separated by the slash character as follows:

```
def split_template_path(template):
"""Split a path into segments and perform a sanity check.  If it detects
'..' in the path it will raise a `TemplateNotFound` error.
"""
pieces = []
for piece in template.split('/'):
    if path.sep in piece \
       or (path.altsep and path.altsep in piece) or \
       piece == path.pardir:
        raise TemplateNotFound(template)
    elif piece and piece != '.':
        pieces.append(piece)
return pieces
```

Comment: Interesting, what is failing in my case is this part of the condition: "if path.sep in piece"  . path.sep is \\ and my piece is 'file\\name.html'. So, I know that the code will work on Linux because the path.sep is /  . It is really inconvenient from Flask that this condition is not passing on Windows.